# Does Eureka support non-RESTful endpoints?

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka

Does Netflix Eureka support non-RESTful endpoints? We have a requirement where clients should be able to discover the AMQP based endpoints provided by RabbitMQ.

It seems main competitors to Eureka such as Consul and Zookeeper are essentially key-value stores and you can store anything in the value.

Comment: Eureka [github page](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) states, it is REST based (Eureka is a REST (Representational State Transfer) based service). Though, Eureka saves IP, port etc. of services, so perhaps it is possible to implement some kind off self-registration of AMQP at Eureka upon start (of AMQP queues), and then other microservices can retrieve this info or better yet, directly send messages to AMQP through interface implementation on sending microservice.

Comment: similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952306/microservice-amqp-and-service-registry-discovery